# Как лучше написать транзакцию

Tags: mysql, транзакции

У меня есть сайт на обычном хостинге, в БД есть таблиця PRODUCT_STOCKS (mysql,innoDB) в которой я храню пару значений товар и его остаток:

```
--------------------------
| id | productId | stock |
--------------------------
|  1 |     1     |  10   |
```

Несколько скриптов паралельно обращаются к таблице читают значение остатка некоторого товара, минусуют от етого остатка некоторое количество, которое необходимо списать и записывают в колонку stock оставшееся доступное количество товара. Я боюсь что может произойти следующая ситуация:
Скажем на остатке есть 10 единиц товара, и 2 скрипта паралельно прочитают даные в таблице и неверно отминусуют количество, пример:

Скрипт 1: Прочитал из бд что на остатке есть 10 единиц, отминусировал 2 единицы и записал в БД что на остатке осталось 8 единиц
Скрипт 2. В тот же момент также прочитал из БД что на остатке есть 10 единиц, отминусовал 3 единицы и записал в БД что на остатке осталось 7 единиц.
Хотя фактически на остатке должно было остатся 5 единиц.

Что б такого не случилось, каждый из скриптов делает ето в транзакции:
Скрипт 1:

```
mysql->START TRANSACTION
mysql->SELECT stock FROM PRODUCT_STOCKS WHERE product=1
дале на PHP я минусую 2 единицы (я знаю что можна средствами mysql, но мне нужно ето зделать на PHP)
mysql->UPDATE PRODUCT_STOCKS SET stock=8 WHERE product=1
mysql->COMMIT
```

Скрипт 2:

```
mysql->START TRANSACTION
mysql->SELECT stock FROM PRODUCT_STOCKS WHERE product=1
дале на PHP я минусую 3 единицы
mysql->UPDATE PRODUCT_STOCKS SET stock=7 WHERE product=1
mysql->COMMIT
```

В результате я ожидаю что сбоя никогда не будет и если я виполню команду
mysql->SELECT stock FROM PRODUCT_STOCKS WHERE product=1
Я получу stock=5

Вопрос: возможен ли при таком алгоритме все таки вариант что значение в колонке stock будет равно 7 а не 5.

```
Возможно для уверенной защиты все таки применить перед началом транзакции
 mysql->LOCK TABLES `PRODUCT_STOCKS` WRITE
А после окончания транзакции
 mysql->UNLOCK TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

Вся операция прекрасно укладывается в один запрос. Запрос - всегда транзакция. То есть несколько запросов и явная внешняя транзакция - не нужны.

Правильное решение - это подрихтовать таблицу и наложить на поле количества ограничение, что значение не может быть отрицательным. Всё, после этого можно сразу вычитать. Варианта, когда было 10, параллельно два скрипта отнимают по 2, но в итоге получается остаток 8 - просто не может быть. А если от 10 попытаются отнимать два скрипта по 6 каждый, то первый отнимет, а второму достанется исходное 4, и ему будет отказано в обновлении - запрос вернёт ошибку нарушения ограничения целостности.

Если версия слишком стара и не реализует CHECK constraint, то идём более сложным путём - проверяем это условие непосредственно в запросе:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET stock = stock - @amount
WHERE {все необходимые условия}
  AND stock >= @amount;
```

Эффект тот же, что и в случае ограничения в структуре. С той лишь разницей, что не будет ошибки, и надо будет анализировать статус операции. Если affected rows = 1, то операция выполнена, а если ноль - то увы...

Comment: На самом деле там все сложнее сначала открывается транзакция делаются выборки из нескольких таблиц БД, потом с этими даными проводятса некоторые вичисления на PHP, потом результат пишется в БД и закрываетса транзакция. И вопрос в том что если запустить один и тот же код паралельно, мне нужно что б пока начата первая транзакция и в ней производится выборка, вичисления и в последствие изменение даных в бд. То что б вторая транзакция которая скажем так "зделает точно те же движения что и первая" - что б вторая транзакция со своими запросами подождала пока не закончится первая транзакция.

Comment: @benzapila Тогда какой смысл, имея одну проблему, задавать вопрос по совсем другой проблеме?

Comment: Поверьте, я хотел как лучше